# Login function with ASync networking request?

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using 'Retrofit' for making asynchronous network requests, how might i right a function for handling logins? For instance i've currently attempted:

```
public UserAuthResponse Login(String username, String password) {

    try {

        Callback<UserAuthResponse> getAuthCallback = new Callback<UserAuthResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError arg0) {

                if (arg0 != null) {
                    if (arg0.getMessage() != null
                            && arg0.getMessage().length() > 0) {
                        Log.e("KFF-Retrofit", arg0.getMessage());
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void success(UserAuthResponse listItem,
                    retrofit.client.Response arg1) {

                Log.e("dg", listItem.getUser().getFirstname());
            }
        };

        service.authUser(username, MD5(password), getAuthCallback);

        return response;

    } catch (RetrofitError e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

But this is flawed: there is no way of returning the 'UserAuthResponse' from the function? How can i pass back the result?

It seems like i need a synchronous call to the web service but then i'm hit with a 'NetworkOnMainThreadException'

What is the best practice for things like this? Sorry about the poor explanation, struggling to form the right words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the things is that when you're using the Callback as your means of getting the results from Retrofit you automatically giving away the possibility of having the response returned inline.  There's a few ways this can be solved.  I suppose it's up to you to choose which one fits best with your design.

You could decide to not use the Callback approach and use the inline result from Retrofit but then you'd need to handle the scheduling yourself otherwise you'll hit the Exception of NetworkOnMainThreadException like you mentioned.

You could also pass in a listener to your login method.  This listener could then be called by the result Callback.  This could be useful if you're trying to hide Retrofit behind some sort of service layer and expose a simple login interface.

```
interface OnLoginListener {
    onLoginSuccessful(UserAuthResponse response);
    onLoginFailed(Throwable t);
}

public void Login(String username, String password, final OnLoginListener listener) {
    Callback<UserAuthResponse> getAuthCallback = new Callback<UserAuthResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError e) {
                    // You can handle Retrofit exception or simply pass them down to the listener as is
                    listener.onLoginFailed(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void success(UserAuthResponse listItem,
                        retrofit.client.Response arg1) {
                    // handle successful case here and pass down the data to the listener
                    listener.onLoginSucessful(listItem);
                }
            };

    service.authUser(username, MD5(password), getAuthCallback);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i went with, initiate the login, assign a 'success' listener, display appropriate message when received through callback. This answer is the best so i will accept it.

Answer (score -1):

use this line i Manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

or use this before network operation (not suggestible)

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= 10) {
        ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
        }
```

Comment: I cant help but feel this suggestion is simply 'hiding the issue' what is a typical best implementation?